# How to use sortDescriptors in order to fetch data from the previous view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data, core-data-migration

The problem I have encountered is that when I fetch the data without any sort descriptor I receive the whole list of data stored in CoreData. However, I want to sort it so that the user would see the data he/she entered in the particular view. The logic is this: I have a TermDefinitionView where user enters the data and then it saves using CoreData. After the user presses "save" button, he/she is relocated to the SetView - the view with the stack of flashcards based on data user entered.

here's SetView():

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct SetView: View {
    
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
   // @FetchRequest(entity: FlashCardData.entity(), sortDescriptors: NSSortDescriptor[key: ])
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: FlashCardData.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \FlashCardData.date, ascending: false)],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "date > %@", Date().addingTimeInterval(-5*60) as NSDate)
    ) var flashCardData: FetchedResults<FlashCardData>

     
    let dataController = DataController.shared
    var removal: (() -> Void)? = nil
    var onRemove: ((SwipeDirection) -> Void)? = nil
    @State private var isShown = false
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    @State private var label: String = "Still Learning"  // Define a label string
    @State private var showPositiveIndicator = false
    @State private var showNegativeIndicator = false
    @State private var showMiddleIndicator = false
    @State private var showEasyIndicator = false
    @State var redirectToSet = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
                .fill(Color.white)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25).stroke(getColor(), lineWidth: 2))  // Here we change the border color based on the swipe direction
                .shadow(radius: 3)

           //rest of the code...
                VStack {
                    ForEach(flashCardData, id: \.self) { flashcards in
                                 //   FlashcardView(flashcard: flashcard)
                      //  Text(flashcards.name ?? "nothing") - have to create a code where it's above
                        VStack {
                            Text(flashcards.term ?? "nothing")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .bold()
                            
                            
                            if isShown {
                                Text(flashcards.definition ?? "nothing")
                                    .font(.largeTitle)
                                    .bold()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                        
            // Display positive indicator
            if showPositiveIndicator {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                            .font(.system(size: 40))
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // Display negative indicator
            if showNegativeIndicator {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "xmark")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .font(.system(size: 40))
                    }
                }
            }
            if showMiddleIndicator {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "light.beacon.min")
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                            .font(.system(size: 40))
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            if showEasyIndicator {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "light.beacon.max")
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                            .font(.system(size: 40))
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 550)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(offset.width / 10)))
        // makes an effect when swiping the card and it gets back if swipped not too much
        .offset(x: offset.width, y: offset.height)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)// changes the position of the card by x - direction
        .onTapGesture {
            isShown.toggle()
        }
        .gesture(
            DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                offset = value.translation
                showPositiveIndicator = offset.width > 50
                showNegativeIndicator = offset.width < -50
                showMiddleIndicator = offset.height > 50
                showEasyIndicator = offset.height < -50
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                if abs(offset.width) > 100 {
                    withAnimation {
                        offset.width = value.translation.width > 0 ? 1000 : -1000
                        onRemove?(value.translation.width > 0 ? .right : .left)
                    }
                } else if abs(offset.height) > 100 {
                    withAnimation {
                        offset.height = value.translation.height > 0 ? 1000 : -1000
                        onRemove?(value.translation.height > 0 ? .up : .down)
                    }
                } else {
                    offset = .zero
                    showPositiveIndicator = false
                    showNegativeIndicator = false
                    showMiddleIndicator = false
                    showEasyIndicator = false
                }
            }

        )
    }
    
    func getColor() -> Color {
        if offset.width > 0 {
          //  label = "Good Job!"  // Change the label based on the swipe direction
            return Color.green
        } else if offset.width < 0 {
          //  label = "Needs Improvement"
            return Color.red
        } else if offset.height > 0{
         //   label = "Still Learning"
            return Color.orange
        }
        else if offset.height < 0 {
            return Color.blue
        }
        else {
            return Color.gray
        }
    }
}
       /* VStack {
            ForEach(flashcards) { flashcard in
                Text(flashcard.name ?? "")
                Text(flashcard.term ?? "")
                Text(flashcard.definition ?? "")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            fetchFlashcards()
        }
    }
    
    private func fetchFlashcards() {
        do {
            try viewContext.performAndWait {
                try viewContext.save()
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error saving view context: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
*/
struct SetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SetView()
    }
}

struct FlashcardView: View {
    var flashcard: FlashCardData
    /*let term: String
    let definition: String
    let name: String
    */
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(flashcard.name ?? "")
            Text(flashcard.term ?? "")
            Text(flashcard.definition ?? "")
        }
    }
```

TermDefinitionView():

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import CoreData

// ViewModel for managing flashcards

struct TermDefinitionView: View {
    // let set: SetView
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: FlashCardData.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \FlashCardData.date, ascending: false)],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "date > %@", Date().addingTimeInterval(-5) as NSDate)
    ) var flashCardData: FetchedResults<FlashCardData>
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = TermDefinitionViewModel()
    @State var name = "" // Separate state for the name
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    let dataController = DataController.shared
    @State var showSet = false
    @Binding var saveSet: Bool
    @State var isShowingSet = false
    //@Binding var redirectToSet: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            NavigationStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Name")
                        .padding(.trailing, 220)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    TextField("Enter name", text: $name)
                        .frame(width: 250)
                        .padding()
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                    List {
                        
                        ForEach(viewModel.termdefpairs.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                            TermView(term: $viewModel.termdefpairs[index].term, definition: $viewModel.termdefpairs[index].definition, tag: $viewModel.termdefpairs[index].tag)
                        
                        }
                        .onDelete { index in
                            self.viewModel.termdefpairs.remove(at: index.first!)
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                        
                      //  redirectToSet.toggle()
                        for testForm in viewModel.termdefpairs {
                            dataController.add(term: testForm.term, name: name, definition: testForm.definition, tag: testForm.tag, date: Date(), context: managedObjectContext)
                           
                        }
                        isShowingSet = true
                        dismiss()
                    }) {
                        Text("Save")
                        NavigationLink(destination: SetView(flashCardData: _flashCardData), isActive: $isShowingSet) {
                            EmptyView()
                            }
                        
                    })
                    
                    Spacer()
                    ForEach(dataController.savedFlash) { x in
                        Text(x.term ?? "nothing")
                        Text(x.definition ?? "nothing")
                        Text(x.tag ?? "nothing")
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        viewModel.addNew()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .resizable()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.title2)
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .padding()
                }
                
            }
        }
    
    }
}


struct TermDefinitionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TermDefinitionView(saveSet: .constant(true))
    }
}

struct TermView: View {
    @Binding var term: String
    @Binding var definition: String
    @Binding var tag: String
    @State private var isTagExpanded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            
            
                if isTagExpanded {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                        Text("Tag")
                            .font(.headline)
                        TextField("Enter tag", text: $tag)
                            .padding()
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                    }
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    isTagExpanded.toggle()
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: isTagExpanded ? "minus.circle.fill" : "plus.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        Text(isTagExpanded ? "Hide Tag" : "Add Tag")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.bottom, -25)
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                Text("Term")
                    .font(.headline)
                TextField("Enter term", text: $term)
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
            }
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                Text("Definition")
                    .font(.headline)
                TextField("Enter definition", text: $definition)
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
            }
            
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct TermAndDefinition: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var term: String
    var definition: String
    var tag: String
    
    
}
```

DataController:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class DataController: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = DataController()
    @Published var savedFlash: [FlashCardData] = []
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<FlashCardData> = FlashCardData.fetchRequest()
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreData")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
    
    func save(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Data saved")
        } catch {
            print("We could not save the data...")
        }
    }
    func add(term: String, name: String, definition: String, tag: String, date: Date, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let data = FlashCardData(context: context)
        data.name = name
        data.id = UUID()
        data.definition = definition
        data.term = term
        data.tag = tag
        data.date = date
        save(context: context)
    }
    
    func edit(data: FlashCardData ,term: String, defintion: String, tag: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        data.term = term
        data.definition = defintion
        data.tag = tag
        save(context: context)
    }
}
```

[image: the result I get without sort descriptor:]

[image: CoreData Entity]

Here's the new @FetchRequest:

```
@FetchRequest(
        entity: FlashCardData.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \FlashCardData.date, ascending: false)],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "date > %@", Date().addingTimeInterval(-5*60) as NSDate)
    ) var flashCardData: FetchedResults<FlashCardData>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This needs to be minimal, and we need to see working examples of your view. The description of what you want is vague, mostly because the views are not available to refer to in your description. Lastly, if you have enough reputation, a screenshot of your Entity is helpful.

Comment: alright, I have made changes

Comment: Do you want to sort or do you want to filter, it's not clear, and for both cases what is the programmatic criteria/logic for this? Or is it only this vague requirement that it was created in the view?

Comment: Actually, I want to sort the data since it's the only way I know for now. I figured out that I could add the date to the Entity and sort data by it. However, this approach might not be the best for an actual app. I edited the code for @fetchRequest.

Comment: You still don't have working code here. We should be able to put your code into a project and be able to run it ourselves.

Comment: Thank you, I have added all views for this functionality.